# JQuery each: Pause & Continue iteration after a click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com', function(data) {

  $.each(data.songs, function(index, song) { 

    //Paused & waiting for a click

    $("#next").click(function() {
         alert("Processing the next object...");
    });

 });
```

I would that JQuery analyze the next object only after the user click on #next element.

I don't need a "timeout", just user action to go to the next object

Comment: Placing code like this into callback forcing an each loop to be suspended until someone clicks will halt the client. You have to just use a next button solution instead of the .each not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not with an each loop.  You'd be better having your click function capture clicks and process an item from the list of items based on a pointer you set.  So something like this:

```
var jsonData = "";
var pointer = 0;
$.getJSON('http://example.com', function(data) {
    jsonData = data;
};
$("#next").click(function() {
    //process item described by pointer
    pointer = pointer + 1;
});
```